# Problem with the trait channels on Google Smart home action action.devices.traits.Channel

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I follow the instructions on the official documentation for the [trait channels](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/channel), my sync JSON is very similar to the example. The attribute section is like this.

```
"availableChannels": [{
    "key": "5f0e8de23cd9b23a5198ca6b",
        "names": ["Fox", "KTVU"],
        "number": "100"
    }, {
    "key": "5f0e8df03cd9b23a5198ca6c",
    "names": ["ABC"],
    "number": "101"
    }, {
    "key": "5f0e8dfa3cd9b23a5198ca6d",
    "names": ["Univision"],
    "number": "102"
}],
```

The sync JSON is valid, but the problem is when I said "Hey google change channel to FOX on TV", the google assistant response

> "OK, playing American Broadcasting Company on The TV"
> then error for
> "Sorry, something went wrong and I am unable to control your device"

The problem is that I don't get any HTTP request on my webhook URL, so something on the google side is broken or maybe my sync is broken but I follow the documentation, this trait is "new" so maybe is something undocumented or is just broken. Any ideas?

Also, there is no error or entries on the Google Cloud Logs

Comment: Can you post the full `SYNC` response your action provides? I am able to get the above attributes to correctly send a `selectChannel` command within a sample app.

Comment: During the certification process, Google guys told me to don't use trait channels, they don't say why

Comment: @devunwired, could you please help me with the same issue. I can provide you the `SYNC` response, its too big for this comment space.

Comment: so the support for Channel trait will drop?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting any smart home request on your fulfillment endpoint can be due to not being able to deliver SYNC for this device properly. Please make sure to reissue your Sync response using Request Sync (or unlinking and relinking for testing), every time you make an update on your channel catalog.

The screenshot that has been posted shows a partial SYNC response. There is a high possibility that the code causing the error comes after the code presented in the screenshot. As already mentioned in the comments further analysis of the SYNC response needs to be done for pointing out the exact root cause.

If you’re still facing issues after that, please report to our public bug tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148).